# Отсутсвие файла Info.plist, даже при сборке только что созданного, никак не изменённого проекта

Tags: qt, mac

Запускаю Qt, создаю новый проект, пытаюсь его собрать и вот:

```
23:35:43: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled...
23:35:43: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
23:35:43: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [untitled.app/Contents/Info.plist] Error 2
23:35:43: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.10.1 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
23:35:43: Прошло времени: 00:00.
```

Попробовал создать чистый `Info.plist` начал ругаться на `main.o`

```
23:38:45: Выполняются этапы для проекта untitled...
23:38:45: Настройки не изменились, этап qmake пропускается.
23:38:45: Запускается: «/usr/bin/make» 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -g -std=gnu++11  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../untitled -I. -I/Volumes/Mac'sRoom/Programs/Mac/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Volumes/Mac'sRoom/Programs/Mac/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Volumes/Mac'sRoom/Programs/Mac/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I. -I/Volumes/Mac'sRoom/Programs/Mac/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Volumes/Mac'sRoom/Programs/Mac/Qt/5.10.1/clang_64/lib -o main.o ../untitled/main.cpp
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** [main.o] Error 2
23:38:45: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.10.1 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
23:38:45: Прошло времени: 00:00.
```

Дело в make?
Или что делать?

Comment: Извините, думал для такой проблемы и так сойдет.
Исправился, так нормально?
Или добавить еще то что у меня в исходниках?

Comment: Снял свой минус.

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Синтактическая ошибка в вашем коде - компилятор подсказывает, что вы что-то начали апострофом (`'`), а не окончили другим апострофом.

Comment: Ааа у меня диск «Mac’sRoom», он же может на это ругаться получается? Завтра попробую переустановить на другой диск, без апострофов... Спасибо! И спасибо, что помогли с оформлением!:)

Comment: Ну да, с этим я знаком, просто не подумал об имени диска... Даже когда вы написали где искать ошибку, долго найти не мог, потом вспомнил про имя диска

Comment: Oшибка не в диске, а *прямо в вашей C/C++ программе*. Просто компилятор нарастил на апостроф, ожидал конечный (парный), перешел вес код до конца (EOF - End Of File - конец файла), но не встретил его. (Когда вам в строке нужно ввести симбол апострофа, нужно его писать как `\'` например `"Mac\'sRoom"`).

Comment: Просто отсутствует один апостроф в `main.cpp`.